# SQL Developer on Mac

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have downloaded SQL Developer, but I can't login.

The error is:

> The Network Adapter could not establish the connection.

Some pages recommend downloading Oracle Instant Client for MacOS, but I don't know how to configure it.

Comment: show us your connection details, tell us where your database is. You DO have a database, yes? 

https://medium.com/oracledevs/i-installed-oracle-sql-developer-now-what-71230b9c9303

Comment: Yep, i need login with system user and then, hr user.

where i see the connections details?

**Thanks a lot**

Comment: ok, where is the database? is it on your machine, on a server in your corp/school domain, in 'the Cloud?'

Comment: OK, your connection is to XE on your laptop. Please confirm that you actually installed Oracle XE on your laptop. And then make sure it's running.

Comment: Dude, im sorry, but, how i see that. Couse, when i downloaded the IDE from Oracle's page, I just click on donwload, and then, I unzip and move to applications. 

I see in the bar: About Oracle SQLDeveloper. Here the ss:
[The photo](https://ibb.co/gZrzxx)

Comment: And sorry, my english isn't good xD!

Comment: Read the link I shared several comments above. There's a reason I shared it.

Comment: Yes, im reading. Is necessary use **Virtualbox?**, i mean, **i use parallels**

**Thans a lots** 
I'll try!

Comment: Well, I'll have to emulate windows.

Thank you very much for your help. You're very kind.

Comment: For xe on a Mac, yeah.. something

Comment: If you grab the vm we have, you'll be up and running as fast as your download speed is.

Comment: Okas! i'll try. Thanks a lot. !!!!!!

Comment: I have a question: I'll always have to open the Virtualbox to use Sqldeveloper ?

Comment: If you want to connect to a database, yes

Comment: If i want to connect a db, but localhost?

Comment: no problem. You just to get a database running on your machine first.

Comment: Hey, What's up. I did what u told me, and, again.. a new error from VirtualBox. but, the problem was, i had not installed de database... So, with a virtual machine, I installed de DB (oracleXE). 


Thank you very much for your help, I appreciated. Greetings from Chile.

Comment: Sorry @imARIEL777 if you had read the medium story, there's a link to a VBOX appliance from Oracle that already has the database on it.